# Select random item from array in Nuxt.js on the server only

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

I currently use the following `component.vue`, however, this makes it evaluate twice (once when rendering *server side*, once on the *client*) and because it is random the user sees the city flash for a second (and change to another one).

What is the most efficient way to prevent this?

```
export default {
        data(){
            return {
                cities: ["Rome", "Amsterdam", "Paris", "Berlin", "London", "Athens", "Madrid"],
                city: ''
            }
        },
        created(){
            this.city = cities[Math.floor(Math.random()*cities.length)];
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can check whether `this.city` already exist before defining it: `this.city = this.city || cities[Math.floor(Math.random()*cities.length)]`;

Comment: thanks, but I can't get it to work that way either, now it doesn't return any city anywhere.

Comment: are you sure it is `cities` and not `this.cities`?

Comment: else, you can try `if (process.browser) this.city = cities[...]`

Comment: The problem is that I can make it execute on the client only but I want it to only run on the server (and then pass the page to the client with the city already there, without the client reevaluating it again, causing another random city to appear)

Comment: ahh. Have you tried [`asyncData`](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/)?

Comment: Thanks a lot, using asyncData on the page level and then using this.$parent.city in the component worked wonderfully. For future reference: you could also use a prop to pass the variable to the component (maybe a little cleaner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `page.vue` I used *asyncData* to set the data *server side* during render, like so:

```
export default {
    components: {
         'component'
    },
    data(){
         return {
             city: ''
         }
    },
    asyncData (context){
         let cities = ["Rome", "Amsterdam", "Paris", "Berlin", "London", "Athens", "Madrid"];
         const city = cities[Math.floor(Math.random()*cities.length)];
         return {
              city: city
         }
    }
}
```

Now that we have the variable `city` with a random city, pass this onto a component using either a prop or by using `this.$parent.city` in the component.